# QProgressDialog don't show up in the front

Tags: qt, progressdialog

I have a QProgressDialog that needs to be popped up when application does the updates. It keeps hiding behind the windows.

```
            dialog->setWindowTitle("Test");
            QLabel * labl  = new QLabel(this);
            labl->setPixmap(QPixmap("icon.png"));
            labl->setText("");
            dialog->setLabel(labl);
            dialog->setCancelButton(NULL);
            dialog->show();
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact you haven't provided enough information to solve the problem, my guess is you have forgotten to raise your dialog (because it was created and hidden earlier). So try to change the code to:

```cpp
....
dialog->show();
dialog->raise();
dialog->activateWindow();
....
```

Comment: What are the window flags of the window hiding the dialog?

Comment: There is no explicit flag being set. It shows up behind the active application window.

Comment: Ok, and what do you do with the dialog? Do you set it non modal? What is its parent?

Comment: It is non modal. It has no parent

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, when i had a modal QDialog and a QProgressDialog and the QDialog would always be on top despite the QProgressDialog coming from the QDialog itself. The issue was the lack of a parent assigned to QProgressDialog; just make sure that you assign the widget that spawns the QProgressDialog to be the parent.